# How do I add a back button after customising the toolbar with other buttons?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uistoryboard, back, uitoolbar

I'm using a `Navigation Controller` for the view but it seems that when I added in a `addbutton` in the swift file it removed my back button.

Also I'm working on a different `Storyboard` so the navigation controller was great for getting back to that `Main.storyboard`.

This is how the project is layed out:

`Main.storyboard` -> storyboard references (storyboard2,storyboard3 etc.)

Navigation Controller -> View Page1 -> View Page2

Now View Page1 has a edit and a add bar button but no back button. I think because I added the buttons in the .swift file the back button has disappeared from the navigation toolbar.

Anyway I can retain that functionality programatically?

Comment: Are you looking to add it programmatically or in the `Storyboard` designer?

Comment: Tbh I've looked into/tried both methods and haven't been able to figure out either way. Adding some more info

Comment: I wonder if this might be able to help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404076/xcode-swift-how-i-implement-a-back-button?rq=1), or if you looked at this yet... Try using an `unwund` segue as it suggests; or a `dismiss()` View Controller option. `dismiss` usually works for me when I want to remove a view controller that's not inside a Nav Controller. For that to work properly however the deployment target has to be `iOS 9.0`.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks.